# React-router cannot find components of other pages in the app

Tags: javascript, react-router, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to set up a test component, which is basically a navigation bar and two components to navigate around. This is what it looks like:

```
class Page1 extends Component{
  render(){
    return (<div>Page1</div>);
  }
}

class Page2 extends Component{
  render(){
    return (<div>Page222</div>);
  }
}

class App extends Component{
  render(){
        console.log('children: ', this.props.children);
    return(
      <div>
        <NavigationBar/>

        {this.props.children}
      </div>

    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route component={App} >
      <Route path="/" component={App}/>
      <Route path="page1" component={Page1}/>
      <Route path="page2" component={Page2}/>
    </Route>
</Router>,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

The navigation bar is just a generic bootstrap navbar  which is appearing fine.
The problem I am having is when I navigate (or click on the Page1 or Page2 buttons), I get the message:

> Cannot GET /page1

Even though the components and the routing is all set up and linking itself also seems to be fine.

I should also mention that the this.props.children is also null.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with the fact that you're passing `App` as a child to `App` in the `Router` render block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `path="/"` to the main `App` Route. Also, you are rendering the `App` component twice within your configuration.  Which won't work properly.  You should change it to:

```
class Page1 extends Component{
  render(){
    return (<div>Page1</div>);
  }
}

class Page2 extends Component{
  render(){
    return (<div>Page222</div>);
  }
}

class Home extends Component {
    render(){
      return(<h1>I AM HOME</h1>);
    }
}

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    console.log('children: ', this.props.children);
    return(
      <div>
        <NavigationBar/>

        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App} >
        <IndexRoute component={Home} /> //Being a different component
        <Route path="page1" component={Page1}/>
        <Route path="page2" component={Page2}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Comment: I tried changing it to exactly what you suggested.
Without the  Route path to "/" it complains that the Locations "/#/" did not match any routes. And when I do include it, well... I get the same error as previous

Comment: oh sorry, see my change you need to add path="/" to the main `App` Route.

Comment: @ZachStoltz Add that ^^^ to the answer, it is the main problem.

Comment: @gfullam added :)

Comment: Alright, so I just realized that if I put a Link to in the Home component, it does actually works.
This probably means my problem is with the navbar, but for this specific topic I suppose it has been solved.
Thanks/