# Changing a component via React-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I made a similar question a month or so ago which seemed to solve all my problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164845/react-router-cannot-find-components-of-other-pages-in-the-app), however I guess the react-router version changed and now that has all gone to the trash? Because now none of that works and the code had some pretty big changes according to my research.

I just want to do some simple routing for a simple webapp, using the same example from my previous thread, I currently have this:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route, IndexRoute, Switch,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
class Page1 extends Component{
  render(){
    return (<div>Page1</div>);
  }
}

class Page2 extends Component{
  render(){
    return (<div>Page222</div>);
  }
}

class Home extends Component {
    render(){
      return(<h1>I AM HOME</h1>);
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
         <Router>
             <Switch>
             <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path="/page1" component={Page1}/>
            <Route exact path="/page2" component={Page2}/>
             </Switch>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Unfortunately, even like this, I still can't navigate in between the different components and keep getting the message

> Cannot GET /page1

I've also noticed that it seems that this.props.children is not used anymore or at least it does not work like it used to.

Anyway, all I want is to simply be able to navigate between the pages and appropriately route them. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: I should also probably mention that I have gone through React Router's documentation and have attempted to follow it as seen [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic), unfortunately the routes still do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like an express.js error, not a client side one. Make sure your server is serving index.html for all urls that don't match anything else.

Comment: That wouldn't be it, I'm not using express.js at all. The way I am connecting the .js files to index.html is through ReactDOM.render().

Comment: @theJuls what are you using for your server?

Comment: just NodeJS' server

Comment: @theJuls the 'http' module?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about.
I haven't really done anything to do server besides the good old 'npm start', because for the purpose of projects like this one I simply never had to, unless now with this update, there is something new I have to do, which I am not aware of.

Comment: @theJuls what does npm start run?

Comment: I'm using the webpack-dev-server

Comment: @theJuls then you need to enable the historyApiFallback option. btw, it uses express internally

Comment: Alright, so I made things simpler and just changed the server to something else, which then made it work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to take into consideration here whenever you say `path=/something` the browser actually try to redirect to the path and it fails, this happens because the `server` whichever server you are using `webpack-dev-server` or `express server`doesn't get  the file. React is basically use to make `SPA` single page application hence at the end of the day you are serving only the first page which `index.html`. Hence you have to tell the server what to serve when you hit a `url`. Most cases you have to serve `index.html` or which ever page that is responsible for your application again.

How to solve this:

If you are using `webpack-dev-server` and you are running it from the same directory as your `index.html` you can go ahead and pass a `--historyApiFallback` flag to `webpack` so something like this:

`$ webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --historyApiFallback`

and you will see which location it will fallback.

More cleaner way of doing it is putting `devServer` config key in your `webpack.config.js`. Which will be something like this:

```
 devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: 'templates/index.html'
    },
  }
```

Here the `index.html` is being served from `templates` directory you can specify the path for your page.

After putting this in your `webpack.config.js`, you can run the server and your component will hopefully render. Hope this helps you.